# Open a port only for internal IP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

I have a Windows server 2008 that is exposed on internet also. So I have two IP for that server - 1. Internal IP 2. External IP.

I want to allow a port only with internal IP.

I have tried to allow the port only from domain.
Also tried at the Scope section adding the internal IP.

Now the problem is that port is blocked from external network. But from internal network if I  try with the external IP and port it allows and I need to block that. It should allow only internal IP.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use netcat
nc -lp1212 -s0.0.0.1

Comment: So are you advising to install netcat?

Comment: netcat can be a useful tool, but I would hardly use it on a public facing computer.

Comment: Completely agree with nephi12. It is not a solution.